# How do i parse a text file in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, text-files

How do i parse a text file in c#?

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: Learn the .NET API.  Such a vague question will only get you vague answers.

Answer (score 8):

Check this interesting approach, [Linq To Text Files](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2006/08/31/734383.aspx), very nice, you only need a `IEnumerable<string>` method, that yields every `file.ReadLine()`, and you do the query.

[Here](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2008/03/18/importing-data-files-with-linq) is another article that better explains the same technique.

Comment: The link for "Here is another article..." is currently dead.

Answer (score 6):

```
using (TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(fullFilePath))
{
  string line;

  while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    // use line here
  }
}
```

set the variable "fullFilePath" to the full path eg. C:\temp\myTextFile.txt

Comment: +1 for actually posting some code that answers the question

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm might look like this:

1. Open Text File
2. For every line in the file:
3. Parse Line

There are several approaches to parsing a line.

The easiest from a beginner standpoint is to use the String methods.

[System.String at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members%28VS.71%29.aspx)

If you are up for more of a challenge, then you can use the System.Text.RegularExpression library to parse your text.

[RegEx at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Comment: Your forgot: "4. Profit"

Comment: Profit should have been number 3.. step 1. Open Text File, step 3. profit..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a helper class such as the one described at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-text-parsing-helper-class.

Answer (score 1):

From years of analyzing CSV files, including ones that are broken or have edge cases, here is my code that passes virtually all of my unit tests:

```
/// <summary>
/// Read in a line of text, and use the Add() function to add these items to the current CSV structure
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s"></param>
public static bool TryParseCSVLine(string s, char delimiter, char text_qualifier, out string[] array)
{
    bool success = true;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder work = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        char c = s[i];

        // If we are starting a new field, is this field text qualified?
        if ((c == text_qualifier) && (work.Length == 0)) {
            int p2;
            while (true) {
                p2 = s.IndexOf(text_qualifier, i + 1);

                // for some reason, this text qualifier is broken
                if (p2 < 0) {
                    work.Append(s.Substring(i + 1));
                    i = s.Length;
                    success = false;
                    break;
                }

                // Append this qualified string
                work.Append(s.Substring(i + 1, p2 - i - 1));
                i = p2;

                // If this is a double quote, keep going!
                if (((p2 + 1) < s.Length) && (s[p2 + 1] == text_qualifier)) {
                    work.Append(text_qualifier);
                    i++;

                    // otherwise, this is a single qualifier, we're done
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Does this start a new field?
        } else if (c == delimiter) {
            list.Add(work.ToString());
            work.Length = 0;

            // Test for special case: when the user has written a casual comma, space, and text qualifier, skip the space
            // Checks if the second parameter of the if statement will pass through successfully
            // e.g. "bob", "mary", "bill"
            if (i + 2 <= s.Length - 1) {
                if (s[i + 1].Equals(' ') && s[i + 2].Equals(text_qualifier)) {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            work.Append(c);
        }
    }
    list.Add(work.ToString());

    // If we have nothing in the list, and it's possible that this might be a tab delimited list, try that before giving up
    if (list.Count == 1 && delimiter != DEFAULT_TAB_DELIMITER) {
        string[] tab_delimited_array = ParseLine(s, DEFAULT_TAB_DELIMITER, DEFAULT_QUALIFIER);
        if (tab_delimited_array.Length > list.Count) {
            array = tab_delimited_array;
            return success;
        }
    }

    // Return the array we parsed
    array = list.ToArray();
    return success;
}
```

However, this function does not actually parse every valid CSV file out there!  Some files have embedded newlines in them, and you need to enable your stream reader to parse multiple lines together to return an array.  Here's a tool that does that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parse a line whose values may include newline symbols or CR/LF
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sr"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string[] ParseMultiLine(StreamReader sr, char delimiter, char text_qualifier)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] array = null;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream) {

        // Read in a line
        sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());

        // Does it parse?
        string s = sb.ToString();
        if (TryParseCSVLine(s, delimiter, text_qualifier, out array)) {
            return array;
        }
    }

    // Fails to parse - return the best array we were able to get
    return array;
}
```

For reference, I placed my [open source CSV code on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-csv-reader/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than a trivial language, use a parser generator. It drove *me* nuts but I've heard good things about [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) (Note: get the manual and read it before you start. If you have used a parser generator other than it before you will not approach it correctly right off the bat, at least I didn't)

Other tools also exist.

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what sort of text file you're on about, its hard to answer. However, the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library has a broad set of tools to help with fixed length file formats, multirecord, delimited etc.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by parse? Parse usually means to split the input into tokens, which you might do if you're trying to implement a programming language. If you're just wanting to read the contents of a text file, look at System.IO.FileInfo.

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement on Pero's answer:

```
FileInfo txtFile = new FileInfo("c:\myfile.txt");
if(!txtFile.Exists) { // error handling }

using (TextReader rdr = txtFile.OpenText())
{
     // use the text file as Pero suggested
}
```

The FileInfo class gives you the opportunity to "do stuff" with the file before you actually start reading from it.  You can also pass it around between functions as a better abstraction of the file's location (rather than using the full path string).  FileInfo canonicalizes the path so it's absolutely correct (e.g. turning / into \ where appropriate) and lets you extract extra data about the file -- parent directory, extension, name only, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, make sure that you have the following namespaces:

```
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Next, we build a function that parses any CSV input string into a DataTable:

```
public DataTable ParseCSV(string inputString) {

  DataTable dt=new DataTable();

  // declare the Regular Expression that will match versus the input string
  Regex re=new Regex("((?<field>[^\",\\r\\n]+)|\"(?<field>([^\"]|\"\")+)\")(,|(?<rowbreak>\\r\\n|\\n|$))");

  ArrayList colArray=new ArrayList();
  ArrayList rowArray=new ArrayList();

  int colCount=0;
  int maxColCount=0;
  string rowbreak="";
  string field="";

  MatchCollection mc=re.Matches(inputString);

  foreach(Match m in mc) {

    // retrieve the field and replace two double-quotes with a single double-quote
    field=m.Result("${field}").Replace("\"\"","\"");

    rowbreak=m.Result("${rowbreak}");

    if (field.Length > 0) {
      colArray.Add(field);                  
      colCount++;
    }

    if (rowbreak.Length > 0) {

      // add the column array to the row Array List
      rowArray.Add(colArray.ToArray());

      // create a new Array List to hold the field values
      colArray=new ArrayList(); 

      if (colCount > maxColCount)
        maxColCount=colCount;

      colCount=0;
    }
  }

  if (rowbreak.Length == 0) {
    // this is executed when the last line doesn't
    // end with a line break
    rowArray.Add(colArray.ToArray());
    if (colCount > maxColCount)
      maxColCount=colCount;
  }

  // create the columns for the table
  for(int i=0; i < maxColCount; i++)
  dt.Columns.Add(String.Format("col{0:000}",i));

  // convert the row Array List into an Array object for easier access
  Array ra=rowArray.ToArray();
  for(int i=0; i < ra.Length; i++) {                

    // create a new DataRow
    DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();

    // convert the column Array List into an Array object for easier access
    Array ca=(Array)(ra.GetValue(i));               

    // add each field into the new DataRow
    for(int j=0; j < ca.Length; j++)
      dr[j]=ca.GetValue(j);

    // add the new DataRow to the DataTable
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }

  // in case no data was parsed, create a single column
  if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
    dt.Columns.Add("NoData");

  return dt;
}
```

Now that we have a parser for converting a string into a DataTable, all we need now is a function that will read the content from a CSV file and pass it to our ParseCSV function:

```
public DataTable ParseCSVFile(string path) {

  string inputString="";

  // check that the file exists before opening it
  if (File.Exists(path)) {

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
    inputString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

  }

  return ParseCSV(inputString);
}
```

And now you can easily fill a DataGrid with data coming off the CSV file:

```
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid DataGrid1;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

  // call the parser
  DataTable dt=ParseCSVFile(Server.MapPath("./demo.csv"));          

  // bind the resulting DataTable to a DataGrid Web Control
  DataGrid1.DataSource=dt;
  DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

Congratulations! You are now able to parse CSV into a DataTable. Good luck with your programming.